# Pdo Row count error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rowcount

I have been trying to use the row count function which is part of the PDO's.. i am using the for each loop to go thru a list of broken parts and then count how many of each part i need to order but using the code  i put bellow its not working and im recving this error

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in W:\xampp\htdocs\ICT_Devices\damage_log\damage_parts_find.php on line 15"

Any help would be awesome my php is located just bellow here and i know that the pdo connect file and also the for each loop work but with the row count side im having issues

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require '../lib/connect/PDO_connect.php';

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM `damage_list`") as $damage_part) {
$parts=$damage_part['Damage'];  
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM damage_log where damage=$parts');

$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $parts. "=".$row_count;
echo "<br>";


}


?>
```

Comment: You should be preparing a parameterised query before the loop and binding `$parts` within the loop then executing the query. Also, if you're only after a rowcount, use `SELECT COUNT(1)` instead. It will perform better and be more compatible across database engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [when using single quote, variables will **not** be expanded](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

So your query *practically* looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM damage_log where damage=$parts
```

Thus an error occurs, and `$stmt` is `FALSE`.

Use double quote may fix your problem.

Also, since you're not quoting `$parts` in your SQL statement, make sure `$parts` is always a number or any other types that do not need quoting.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you $stmt is not an object.

This is likely because your query is bad ... the `$parts` is not interpreted inside single quotes, and is thus in the query literally.